# Two-Parent Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, class

If we do class inheritance, I'd say a reasonable assumption would be that this code would work:

```py
 class AddsFunct:
    def __init__(self):
        self.greet1 = "hello"


class AddsFunct2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.greet2 = "world"


class FullName(AddsFunct, AddsFunct2):
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        super(AddsFunct, self).__init__()
        super(AddsFunct2, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

    def printer(self):
        print(self.greet1 + " " + self.name + " " + self.surname + " " + self.greet2)


fullname = FullName("John", "Doe")
fullname.printer()
```

The only way I could make this run is changing the super calls to:

```py
class FullName(AddsFunct, AddsFunct2):
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        super().__init__()
        super(AddsFunct, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
```

How is this supposed to be done in a clean and simple way ?

Comment: A good watch, if you really want to understand `super`, is Raymond Hettinger's PyCon talk [Super Considered Super](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) or read the corresponding blog post

Comment: I have noticed that if I do anything other than actually trying things, I learn slower. So i haven't read a book of any other language, and seems ok to me. For python, I just looked at code snippets. Do you have a different experience ? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: certainly, I think actually trying things out in a context where it is meaningful to some problem that I'm trying to solve is generally the best way to learn, but I also just read other code bases (sometimes because I'm curious about implementation details of some library that I use) or by reading books, or articles/blogs, or watching / attending talks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you pass to super will point to where in the MRO (Method Resolution Order) will start looking for the parent method. Instead, you can simply refer to classes directly.

```
class FullName(AddsFunct, AddsFunct2):
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        AddsFunct.__init__(self)
        AddsFunct2.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
```

The another option, which avoids the need to refer to the classes directly, but requires changing all the parent classes, is to make them call super by themselves:

```
class AddsFunct:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.greet1 = "hello"


class AddsFunct2:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.greet2 = "world"


class FullName(AddsFunct, AddsFunct2):
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
```

This will call all the supers in MRO, eventually ending up at `objects` class `__init__`.

Comment: the last option fails for me, but i'll try again. ps: yeah keeps failing.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: the second option (`super().__init__()` in all the classes) is the correct way and the code above works fine

Comment: oh, all the classes need to use super for this to work, thank you, this is a nice answer.

Comment: @Anentropic it's not really anymore "correct" than the first way. The second way is cooperative multiple inheritance, but that is a design choice, and you can use multiple inheritance in different ways